# Mach-O Linker error C: Happens when I use time.h

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, llvm

When I try to use `time.h`, to do an assignment or elsewhere, i get a the error `:Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) error with ex: _tm_min referenced from:` and no other clue. I tried switching compilers from gnu99 to c99 to c11 to c98... I did tests and it only occurs when i try to call `time.h`, not when i include it, whether directly or indirectly.

Comment: I think you're missing something in the error. Don't you mean "Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) error with exit code (some number)"?